# Nginx geoip does not show the country in the logs

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location, geoip

I am using a public repo for nginx configured for geolocation with geoip, but I am getting dashes in the fields `$geoip2_data_country_code $geoip2_data_country_name'`. I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.11

COPY GeoLite2-Country.mmdb /usr/share/geoip/

# Install libmaxminddb and ngx_http_geoip2_module

ENV MAXMIND_VERSION=1.2.1

RUN set -x \
  && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    alpine-sdk \
    perl \
  && git clone https://github.com/leev/ngx_http_geoip2_module /ngx_http_geoip2_module \
  && wget https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb/releases/download/${MAXMIND_VERSION}/libmaxminddb-${MAXMIND_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && tar xf libmaxminddb-${MAXMIND_VERSION}.tar.gz \
  && cd libmaxminddb-${MAXMIND_VERSION} \
  && ./configure \
  && make \
  && make check \
  && make install \
  && apk del .build-deps

# TODO fix issue with non zero return code

RUN ldconfig || :

# Install nginx

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.15.11

RUN GPG_KEYS=B0F4253373F8F6F510D42178520A9993A1C052F8 \
    && CONFIG="\
        --prefix=/etc/nginx \
        --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
        --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules \
        --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
        --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
        --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
        --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
        --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
        --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
        --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
        --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
        --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
        --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
        --user=nginx \
        --group=nginx \
        --with-http_ssl_module \
        --with-http_realip_module \
        --with-http_addition_module \
        --with-http_sub_module \
        --with-http_dav_module \
        --with-http_flv_module \
        --with-http_mp4_module \
        --with-http_gunzip_module \
        --with-http_gzip_static_module \
        --with-http_random_index_module \
        --with-http_secure_link_module \
        --with-http_stub_status_module \
        --with-http_auth_request_module \
        --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic \
        --with-threads \
        --with-stream \
        --with-stream_ssl_module \
        --with-stream_ssl_preread_module \
        --with-stream_realip_module \
        --with-stream_geoip_module=dynamic \
        --with-http_slice_module \
        --with-mail \
        --with-mail_ssl_module \
        --with-compat \
        --with-file-aio \
        --with-http_v2_module \
    --add-dynamic-module=/ngx_http_geoip2_module \
    " \
    && addgroup -S nginx \
    && adduser -D -S -h /var/cache/nginx -s /sbin/nologin -G nginx nginx \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        gcc \
        libc-dev \
        make \
        openssl-dev \
        pcre-dev \
        zlib-dev \
        linux-headers \
        curl \
        gnupg1 \
        libxslt-dev \
        gd-dev \
        geoip-dev \
    && curl -fSL https://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz -o nginx.tar.gz \
    && curl -fSL https://nginx.org/download/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION.tar.gz.asc  -o nginx.tar.gz.asc \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && found=''; \
    for server in \
        ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net \
        hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
        hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
        pgp.mit.edu \
    ; do \
        echo "Fetching GPG key $GPG_KEYS from $server"; \
        gpg --keyserver "$server" --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys "$GPG_KEYS" && found=yes && break; \
    done; \
    test -z "$found" && echo >&2 "error: failed to fetch GPG key $GPG_KEYS" && exit 1; \
    gpg --batch --verify nginx.tar.gz.asc nginx.tar.gz \
    && rm -rf "$GNUPGHOME" nginx.tar.gz.asc \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src \
    && tar -zxC /usr/src -f nginx.tar.gz \
    && rm nginx.tar.gz \
    && cd /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION \
    && ./configure $CONFIG --with-debug \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && mv objs/nginx objs/nginx-debug \
    && mv objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so \
    && mv objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so \
    && mv objs/ngx_http_geoip_module.so objs/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so \
    && mv objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module.so objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so \
    && ./configure $CONFIG \
    && make -j$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) \
    && make install \
    && rm -rf /etc/nginx/html/ \
    && mkdir /etc/nginx/conf.d/ \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
    && install -m644 html/index.html /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
    && install -m644 html/50x.html /usr/share/nginx/html/ \
    && install -m755 objs/nginx-debug /usr/sbin/nginx-debug \
    && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module-debug.so \
    && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module-debug.so \
    && install -m755 objs/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module-debug.so \
    && install -m755 objs/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_stream_geoip_module-debug.so \
    && ln -s ../../usr/lib/nginx/modules /etc/nginx/modules \
    && strip /usr/sbin/nginx* \
    && strip /usr/lib/nginx/modules/*.so \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/nginx-$NGINX_VERSION \
    \
    # Bring in gettext so we can get `envsubst`, then throw
    # the rest away. To do this, we need to install `gettext`
    # then move `envsubst` out of the way so `gettext` can
    # be deleted completely, then move `envsubst` back.
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .gettext gettext \
    && mv /usr/bin/envsubst /tmp/ \
    \
    && runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/lib/nginx/modules/*.so /tmp/envsubst \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )" \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .nginx-rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps \
    && apk del .gettext \
    && mv /tmp/envsubst /usr/local/bin/ \
    \
    # Bring in tzdata so users could set the timezones through the environment
    # variables
    && apk add --no-cache tzdata \
    \
    # forward request and error logs to docker log collector
    && ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.vh.default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And the two files `nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so; # GeoIP2

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # GeoIP2
    geoip2 /usr/share/geoip/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb {
        $geoip2_data_country_code source=$remote_addr country iso_code;
        $geoip2_data_country_name source=$remote_addr country names en;
    }

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # GeoIP2
    log_format  main_geo  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                          '$geoip2_data_country_code $geoip2_data_country_name';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main_geo; # GeoIP2

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And `nginx.vh.default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

According to [this page](https://bubelov.com/blog/nginx-geoip/) if I do `docker run --rm -p 80:80 bubelov/nginx-alpine-geoip2` then I will get the correct log:

```
183.88.21.120 - - [16/Apr/2019:09:08:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 
200 612 "-" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0" "-" 
TH Thailand
```

But in my case it is the following:

```
192.168.3.1 - - [15/Jun/2022:10:46:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "10.0.8.83" - -
```

The actual nginx configuration file is the following:

```
events{}
# See blow link for Creating NGINX Plus and NGINX Configuration Files 
# https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/managing-configuration-files/
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # The identifier Backend is internal to nginx, and used to name this specific upstream
    upstream backend {
    # BACKEND_HOST is the internal DNS name used by the Backend Service inside the Kubernetes cluster 
    # or in the services list of the docker-compose. 
    server ${BACKEND_HOST}:${BACKEND_PORT};
    }
    server {
        listen ${NODE_PORT};
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        location /api/ {
        resolver 127.0.0.11; 
        #nginx will not crash if host is not found    
        # The following statement will proxy traffic to the upstream
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you verified that `libmaxminddb` works as described in the article?

Answer (score 1):

Wait a second, your IP `192.168.3.1` is a private one. So it can not have a location identified.

```
> mmdblookup --file GeoLite2-Country.mmdb --ip 192.168.3.1

Could not find an entry for this IP address (192.168.3.1)
```

More on IP ranges: https://www.arin.net/reference/research/statistics/address_filters/

Comment: `192.168.3.1` is the `remote_addr`, but if you check the log there is the `10.0.8.83`, which is the `http_x_forwarded_for` and this is the IP that the `GeoLite2` uses., as far as I know. Do I miss something here?

Comment: as far as I get your geoip config uses `remote_addr` to define the location? in the article you mentioned the remote_addr is `183.88.21.120` which is a public Thai IP

Comment: btw, `10.0.8.83` is also a private range IP, if you want to test it, try making a call from outside your network. 

These IPs will not produce valid location results: `10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255`, `172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255`, `192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255`

Answer (score 1):

Below is the list of Private Network Subnets. Inside your VPN (Virtual Private  Network) network admins can assign any subnet to any location.

```
RFC 1918 name   IP address range    Number of addresses     Largest CIDR block (subnet mask)    Host ID size    Mask bits   Classful description[Note 1]
24-bit block    10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255   16777216    10.0.0.0/8 (255.0.0.0)  24 bits     8 bits  single class A network
20-bit block    172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255     1048576     172.16.0.0/12 (255.240.0.0)     20 bits     12 bits     16 contiguous class B networks
16-bit block    192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255   65536   192.168.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0)    16 bits     16 bits     256 contiguous class C networks
```

Only Public IP addresses can be found in `GeoLite2-Country.mmdb`. That's why the your IP `192.168.3.1` does not return any location.

Comment: `192.168.3.1` is the `remote_addr`, but if you check the log there is the `10.0.8.83`, which is the `http_x_forwarded_for` and this is the IP that the `GeoLite2` uses., as far as I know. Do I miss something here?

Comment: This `nginx` is reached after Load Balancer on cloud or you might be using this nginx to host some internal application. In case of cloud you have to change the settings to pass the actual client IP, in case of second use case one have to be inside VPN in order to access it. `http_x_forwarded_for` might contains the IP of Cloud Load Balancer, if not configured to pass the actual client IP. Again `10.0.8.83` is private IP won't be present in `GeoLite2-Country.mmdb`.

Comment: Nginx is reached after load balancer on on-premices virtual machine. This is equivalent to cloud, right? Do you have any examples of right configuration in such a case?

Comment: Need to know which load balancer, in order to configure, or to provide configurations.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the actual Nginx configuration that I am using for proxy.